# Date ranges using recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion

I have a query that returns results that look like the create table query below

```
create table #testresults
(
  pat_id int,
  fill_date date,
  script_end_date date,
  drug_class char(3),
  distinctDrugs int
)
```

There are seven different categories of drugs that a pat_id can be given.  The `distinctDrugs` column is the number of different drugs that a `pat_id` can be given within the time frame of `fill_date` and `script_end_date`.  The results of running the query look like:
[image]

Each `pat_id` has many different `fill_date` and `script_end_date` time periods.  These different time periods have a different `drug_class` and `distinctDrugs` per row.  The right two columns on this example are indicative of what I need: I need on each row, for each `fill_date` and `script_end_date` the `drug_class` and`distinctDrugs` for each `drug_class`.  I used this query to add the two right-most columns to my base view

```
select distinct
 t.pat_id
,t.fill_date
,t.script_end_date
,t.drug_class
,t.distinctDrugs
,h3a.drug_class as h3aDrugClass
,h3a.distinctDrugs
from #temp as t
left join 
(
    select 
     pat_id
    ,fill_date
    ,script_end_date
    ,drug_class
    ,distinctDrugs
    from #temp 
    where drug_class='h3a'
) as h3a on h3a.pat_id=t.pat_id and h3a.fill_date between t.fill_date and t.script_end_date and t.drug_class !=h3a.drug_class
where h3a.drug_class is not null
```

It would be easy enough to do this for the rest of the `drug_class` columns, but this isn't remotely efficient.  Is there a way to do this much more simply using recursion (or any other manner for that matter)?

EDIT:
Here is the final product of what I was looking for:

```
select distinct 
 f.pat_id
,f.fill_date
,f.script_end_date
,case when h3a.drug_class is null then 'H3A' else 'H3A' end as H3A
,isnull(h3a.distinctDrugs,0) as h3aCounts
,case when h4b.drug_class is null then 'H4B' else 'H4B' end as H4B
,isnull(h4b.distinctDrugs,0) as h4bCounts
,case when h6h.drug_class is null then 'H6H' else 'H6H' end  as H6H
,isnull(h6h.distinctDrugs,0) as h6hCounts
,case when h2s.drug_class is null then 'H2S' else 'H2S' end as H2S 
,isnull(h2s.distinctDrugs,0) as h2sCounts
,case when h2e.drug_class is null then 'H2E' else 'H2E' end  as H2E
,isnull(h2e.distinctDrugs,0) as h2eCounts
,case when h2f.drug_class is null then 'H2F' else 'H2F' end as H2F
,isnull(h2f.distinctDrugs,0) as h2fCounts
,case when j7c.drug_class is null then 'J7C' else 'J7C' end  as J7C
,isnull(j7c.distinctDrugs,0) as j7cCounts
from familyStrata as f
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,distinctDrugs
    ,fill_date
    from familyStrata 
    where drug_class='h3a'
) as h3a on h3a.pat_id=f.pat_id and h3a.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='h4b'
) as h4b on h4b.pat_id=f.pat_id and h4b.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='h6h'
) as h6h on h6h.pat_id=f.pat_id and h6h.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='h2f'
) as h2f on h2f.pat_id=f.pat_id and h2f.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='h2s'
) as h2s on h2s.pat_id=f.pat_id and h2s.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='h2e'
) as h2e on h2e.pat_id=f.pat_id and h2e.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
left join 
(
    select
     pat_id
    ,drug_class
    ,fill_date
    ,distinctDrugs
    from familyStrata
    where drug_class='j7c'
) as j7c on j7c.pat_id=f.pat_id and j7c.fill_date between f.fill_date and f.script_end_date
```

This is actually rather fast, but is in no way remotely elegeant/extensible.  Here is what the result set should look like:
[image]

You can see the number the drug_class and the distinctDrugs for each different drug, for each time period.  Now, is there a much more elegant solution to this problem than this?

Comment: It is not very clear what your *final* result set should look like. Do you want a separate column for every drug class that coincides in the time with the one in the current row?

Comment: It is now certainly clear that you want one row per pat_id and that there may be many drug classes per row. However, it is still not clear how you want to present the multiple classes in the final output. One option could be to use one column for a CSV-list of class names and, probably, another column for a CSV-list of corresponding counts. Alternatively you could have separate columns for classes and their counts. Or you could reserve column names for all existing classes and thus show only counts (or NULLs) in them. (Still another option would be to process an unpivoted output in your app!)

Comment: I'll be updating this question shortly with the query that I used to solve it and the resultant result set the query produced in hopes of finding a more extensible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, recursion isn't the best method for doing this.  I settled with

```
select
 pat_id
,fill_date
,script_end_date
,'h3a' as h3a, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h3a' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h3aCounts
,'h4b' as h4b, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h4b' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h4bCounts
,'h6h' as h6h, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h6h' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h6hCounts
,'h2e' as h2e, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h2e' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h2eCounts
,'h3a' as h2f, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h2f' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h2fCounts
,'h3a' as h2s, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='h2s' then distinctDrugs end),0) as h2sCounts
,'h3a' as j7c, coalesce(sum(case when drug_class='j7c' then distinctDrugs end),0) as j7cCounts
,row_number() over(order by pat_id) as rn
from x
group by pat_id,fill_date,script_end_date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you do recursive queries using common table expressions (CTEs). Here's how:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx